# Pass variables to nested function calls

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

Simply I show you the code:

I have function like this:

```
function eachLang($callback){
    global $langs;
    foreach($langs as $ln=>$lnnm){
        call_user_func($callback,$ln);
    }
}
```

Next I you it like this:

```
$vf = new ValidFluent($_POST);
eachLang(function($ln){
    $vf->name('title_'.$ln)->required()->maxSize(100);
});
```

How to pass `$vf` object to the callback function easily?

I mean this way `$vf` is undefined in callback

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `use` in your callback function to pass variables. Add the `&` before the variable name to pass by reference:

```
$vf = new ValidFluent($_POST);
eachLang(function($ln) use (&$vf) {
    $vf->name('title_'.$ln)->required()->maxSize(100);
});
```

There's some more information on anonymous functions and `use` here:
http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: `$ln` is not prob. `$vf` is